# Stereoscopic Street View

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I want to implement stereoscopic view for street view, Google Map and Google Street View app does like this: http://googledevelopers.blogspot.fr/2015/10/bringing-google-cardboard-and-vr-to.html

Is there API to turn on/off stereoscopic view in StreetViewPanoramaFragment? Not available yet?